# how to query for exact mach in unknown number of subfields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where documents can have an unknown number of sub documents:

```
"agent_id": {
    "0":"1234",
    "1":"2234",...etc
```

How do I search for an exact match in all the `agent_id` sub-fields?

Comment: what do you mean by *unknown number of sub documents* ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically create an object with properties that are a concatenation of the embedded document name `agent_id` with the dot (.) and the field name, enclosed in quotes, something like this:

```
var query = {
        "agent_id.0": "78343",
        "agent_id.1": "78343",
        "agent_id.2": "78343",
        "agent_id.3": "78343",
        ...
        "agent_id.n": "78343"
    }
```

One way to create the object is generate the sub-documents keys with **[mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/#map-reduce)**. The following demonstrates this approach. In the Map-Reduce operation, an array of keys in the `agent_id` subdocument is generated to an output collection "collection_keys" and then used to produce the **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** query expression:

Suppose you populate a sample collection

```
db.collection.insert([
    {
        "agent_id": {
            "0":"1234",
            "1":"2234",
            "56":"8451",
            "74":"1475",
            "10":"1234"
        }
    },
    {
        "agent_id": {
            "5":"5874",
            "18":"2351" 
        }           
    } 
])
```

Running the following mapReduce operation

```
var mr = db.runCommand({
    "mapreduce" : "collection",
    "map" : function() {
        for (var key in this.agent_id) { emit(key, null); }
    },
    "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { 
        return null  
    }, 
    "out": "collection" + "_keys"
});

var query = { "$or": [] },
    value = "1234";
db[mr.result].distinct("_id").forEach(function (key){    
    var obj = {};
    obj["agent_id." + key] = value;
    query["$or"].push(obj)
});

printjson(query);
```

will produce:

```
{
    "$or" : [
        {
                "agent_id.0" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.1" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.10" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.18" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.5" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.56" : "1234"
        },
        {
                "agent_id.74" : "1234"
        }
    ]
})
```

You can then use the query document in your **[`find()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)** query:

```
db.collection.find(query)
```

which will produce the result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("561d5312cd05efc95a1ea1f4"),
    "agent_id" : {
        "0" : "1234",
        "1" : "2234",
        "56" : "8451",
        "74" : "1475",
        "10" : "1234"
    }
}
```